# ACM won't validate the SSL certificate for my Route53 domain

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-route53, aws-certificate-manager

I am trying to host a React app on AWS with a custom domain by following [this tutorial](https://medium.com/dailyjs/a-guide-to-deploying-your-react-app-with-aws-s3-including-https-a-custom-domain-a-cdn-and-58245251f081) (minus the continuous development stuff). So far I am able to visit my website from both the S3 bucket and the CloudFront endpoints. I have a domain on Route53 (we'll call it example.com) that I purchased a month or so ago and a hosted zone for it. My problem starts here: I am requesting an ACM certificate (on us-east-1) for `example.com`, `www.example.com`, and `*.example.com` and choosing to validate it through DNS. In the next page I am creating records for the 3 domain entries and I can see that they appear on the hosted zone records as CNAME's (only 2, though, as `example.com` and `*.example.com` are identical) but it still says: "Validation not complete". I've been all morning busy with this. I have tried clicking the create record buttons again, requesting more certificates, etc. I know this can take time but it's been 5 hours.

Comment: It should be less than 30 mins. Can you share your screenshot?

Comment: @FranxiHidro Here you go: https://imgur.com/a/3qSUxlt

Comment: Did you create a record in Route53 (cname)?

Comment: @FranxiHidro The CNAME records that appear on the screenshot were created from ACM.

Comment: I use dnschecker to find out the NS and It's different from your screenshot. Maybe you re-create the hosted zone and forget to update it on DNS provider.

Comment: @FranxiHidro I have actually done this before a month or so ago and the validation was instantaneous but I had to delete the hosted zone and make this new one. Could that be a problem? My domain provided is Route53 itself.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231077/discussion-between-franxi-hidro-and-alberto-vilches).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My issue was that the Name Servers under "Hosted zone details" were not the same as the ones in my registered domain. I believe this might have happened because I had to re-create the hosted zone. The first time I did what's detailed in the post it worked without issue, but that was when I was using the hosted zone that gets automatically generated when you purchase your first domain [proof](https://aws.amazon.com/route53/faqs/). I replaced the domain's NS's with the hosted zone's and re-requested a certificate. In around 5 minutes it was validated.